# Растянуть элемент (с классом .object) вертикально

Tags: html, вёрстка, css, дизайн

Элемент `.object` с желтой границей никак не хочет растягиваться по блоку, там вы видите сверху табличка, и снизу табличка, а между ними желтый элемент, как растянуть его height, чтобы пропорционально все смотрелось? Если ставить фиксированную высоту, то все сработает, он растянется как надо, но вот % никак ни хочет? см.
**css**

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute; left: 5%; top: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #c2c2c2;
  opacity: 0.7;
 }

.main-table { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
 .top-threads { position: relative; top: 0; left:0; width: 100%; float: left; }
 .bottom-threads { width: 100%; position: relative; bottom: 0; float: left; }
 .object { position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; height: 10%; border: 2px solid yellow; }
```

и **html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
         <table border="1" class="top-threads"><tr><td>thread  1</td><td>thread 2</td><td>thread  3</td><td>thread 4</td></tr></table>
       <div class="object">
        <div> item 1 </div>
        <div> item 2 </div>
        <div> item 3 </div>
        </div>
       <table border="1" class="bottom-threads"><tr><td> thread 1</td><td>thread 2</td><td>thread 3</td></tr></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

и [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/eh7Hm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, когда у родителя не задана высота, элемент не будет растягиваться, т.к. не от чего считать проценты. Не совсем вас понял, вы хотите, чтобы две таблицы и div.object делили родителя на три равные части?

Comment: да, глуповато.